# How many Q are there in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

The Q Continuum is an extradimensional plane of existence inhabited by a race of beings known as the Q. The term could also refer to the Q society itself. Per Memory Alpha we're told of 8 individual Q plus the addition of Riker's temporary promotion to Q status brings the total number to 9.

- Q
- Q2
- Quinn
- Q (female)
- Q (Colonel)
- Q (Junior)
- Q (Judge)
- William T. Riker (temporarily)
- Amanda Rogers

The question is;

> If they're an actual race, how many Q are there?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFRpFkZFrOU

Comment: Based on the scenes from "Death Wish" and "The Q and the Grey", potentially dozens, maybe more.

Comment: 42 one would assume

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the events of "The Q and the Grey", there are potentially *hundreds* of Q. In the battle scene we see scores of Rebel tents and tens of campfires. Assuming that each Q has their own tent, then just one side has approx a hundred Q. One would assume that the forces of the status quo (e.g. who're winning) would have at least that number again, maybe more.

[image]

Comment: I would expect there to be more. Guess we could quote Alexander Rozhenko; "The higher, the fewer".

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to interpret this question as 'How many Q do we know about', as otherwise we'd be merely speculating.

We *know of* a total of **20** Q:

- *The* Q (played by John de Lancie)
- Female Q
- Q Junior
- Colonel Q
- Amanda Rogers' Mother
- Amanda Rogers' Father
- Amanda Rogers
- Q2
- Quinn
- Will Riker (for a brief period of time)
- The Supervisory Q
- Male and Female Q at the ranch house in the Q Continuum
- A Q in the form of a hound dog
- A Q reading 'The New' Magazine
- A Q reading 'The Old' book
- The man playing pinball
- Two men playing croquet
- A scarecrow

[Source](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q_(species))

That is not to say that there *are* only 20 Q including Riker; it's just saying that we only ***know of*** 20 being who were a Q

Comment: Please note: I'll add pictures later; I'm on my iPad at the moment and it's not fun adding pictures from here!

Comment: Weren't there far more in the non-canon books?

Comment: @DVK - Many, many more. As many as the plot would allow.

Comment: Another from the books, but is Trelane not officially seen as a Q?